# Подключение к БД. Fat-Free Framework

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, framework

Подключаюсь к БД так:

```
F3::set('DB', new DB('
    mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;
    dbname=test',
    'root',
    ''
));
```

И делаю запрос:

```
DB::sql('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 8steps_tmpUser WHERE email = "'.$mail.'" AND code = "'.$key.'"')
```

Но ничего не выходит. Выводит ошибку:

> Table 'test.8steps_tmpuser' doesn't exist

Что делать? Помогите.

Comment: названия таблиц не должны начинаться на цифру!

Comment: 2 @johniek_comp и где написано что нельзя называть таблицы где первый символ цифра? Что за бред!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Table 'test.8steps_tmpuser' doesn't
> exist

Нет таблицы **8steps_tmpuser**

Comment: но она-то есть. в этом вся и фишка. Пишет что её нет, но она есть

Comment: Убедитесь что она есть именно в БД test. Убедитесь в правильности написания имени таблицы.

Comment: Если есть сообщение 
>Table 'test.8steps_tmpuser' doesn't exist

Значит таблицы нет!

Может ты смотришь на разные сервера? Локальный и на хостинге? Может есть БД в которой есть такая таблица, но ты используешь не её. Мало инфы очень. ошибка понятна, из этого следует что сам вопрос решен, а вот почему её нет это другой вопрос!

Comment: Скачите что ещё нужно

Comment: Ну нам нужно много чего, но раз написано что нет таблицы, значит её нет, и не переспоришь!

Проверь к какой БД подключаешься, залезь в неё через phpmyadmin выложи скрин всех таблиц, или просто скопи пасти их!

Comment: 8steps_location_city
8steps_tmpuser
8steps_users
Такие таблицы есть

Comment: Так. 

Ты под виндой или unix сидишь?

если под unix или на сервере где работаешь unix тогда вместо
>8steps_tmpUser 

сделай

>8steps_tmpuser

Comment: Прокатило? :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать `select` запрос из другой таблицы, не начинающийся с цифрового символа.

Comment: Не работает

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
    function ($f3) {
        $f3->set('html_title','Список товаров');
        $product=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'product');
        $products=$product->find();
        $f3->set('products',$products);
        $f3->set('content','blog_home.html');
        echo Template::instance()->render('layout.html');
    }
);
```

Данные таскаю через JSON:

```
$f3->route('GET /api/',
    function($f3) {
        $f3->set('html_title','Список JSON товаров');
        $result = array();
        $product=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'product');
        $products=$product->find();
        foreach ($products as $prod)
        //$f3->set('products',$products);
        array_push($result,$prod->cast());
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
);
```

Но данные можно вытащить например как: `echo $prod->поле в БД`